# Unexpected output by tr

Tags: linux, command-line

I am surprised by this:

```
$ echo "§" | tr '§' 'a'
aa
```

I was expecting a single `a`.

Why is this?

Comment: Interesting question, it also is the case for 'â', 'è', ..., but not for '#', '@', ...

Comment: Might be related to `§` not being a 7-bit ASCII character? In fact, on my system `echo -n § | hexdump` gives `0000000 a7c2`. And `a7c2` is the UTF-8 encoding of `§`.

Answer (score 2):

`tr` (at least the GNU implementation) cannot correctly handle multi-byte characters.  See this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228570/330217

Apparently `§` is a two-byte character in your locale, so your first set of characters for `'§'` contains two bytes. The second set `'a'` is extended to the length of the first set, so effectively your command

```
tr '§' 'a'
```

behaves like

```
tr '<1st byte of §><2nd byte of §>' 'aa'
```

similar to

```
echo foobar | tr 'abc' 'x'
```

As a **workaround** you can **use `sed`** instead of `tr`.

```
$ echo "§"|sed 's/§/a/g'
a
```